# Am I using ArrayLists wrong in Zig when performing simple variable assignment changes function behaviour?

Tags: zig

I have been doing Advent of Code this year, to learn Zig, and I discovered something during Day 5 that really confused me. So: mild spoilers for Day 5 of Advent of Code 2022, I guess?

I decided to implement my solution to Day 5 as an ArrayList of ArrayLists of U8s, which has ended up working well. My full solution file is [here](https://github.com/daogilvie/aoc2022/blob/main/src/day5.zig) (probably terribly un-idiomatic Zig, but we all have to start somewhere).

As part of my solution, I have a function, which I call moveCrates, on a struct which wraps my arraylist of arraylists.

The relevant part of the struct declaration looks as so:

```
const BunchOfStacks = struct {
    stacks: ArrayList(ArrayList(u8)),
    ...
```

This function is [here](https://github.com/daogilvie/aoc2022/blob/d82304dbf855eb6f877e7d37e3b666206fd169f1/src/day5.zig#L36-L41), and looks like this:

```
    fn moveCrates(self: *BunchOfStacks, amount: usize, source: usize, dest: usize) !void {
        const source_height = self.stacks.items[source - 1].items.len;
        const crate_slice = self.stacks.items[source - 1].items[(source_height - amount)..];
        try self.stacks.items[dest - 1].appendSlice(crate_slice);
        self.stacks.items[source - 1].shrinkRetainingCapacity(source_height - amount);
    }
```

You can note that I refer 3 times to the source list by the very verbose reference `self.stacks.items[source - 1]`. This is not how I first wrote this function. I first wrote it like below:

```
    fn moveCrates(self: *BunchOfStacks, amount: usize, source: usize, dest: usize) !void {
        var source_list: ArrayList(u8) = self.stacks.items[source - 1];
        const source_height = source_list.items.len;
        const crate_slice = source_list.items[(source_height - amount)..];
        try self.stacks.items[dest - 1].appendSlice(crate_slice);
        source_list.shrinkRetainingCapacity(source_height - amount);
    }
```

But this second form, where I make a local variable for my convenience, DOES NOT GIVE THE CORRECT RESULTS! It compiles fine, but seems to always point `source_list` to the same internal `ArrayList(u8)` (whichever one it first picks) regardless of what the value of `source` is. This means that the test example produces incorrect output.

This function is called within a loop, like so:

```
    while (instructions.next()) |_| {
        // First part is the verb, this is always "move" so skip it
        // Get the amount next
        const amount: usize = try std.fmt.parseInt(usize, instructions.next().?, 10);
        // now skip _from_
        _ = instructions.next();
        // Now get source
        const source: usize = try std.fmt.parseInt(usize, instructions.next().?, 10);
        // Now skip _to_
        _ = instructions.next();
        // Now get dest
        const dest: usize = try std.fmt.parseInt(usize, instructions.next().?, 10);

        var crates_moved: usize = 0;
        while (crates_moved < amount) : (crates_moved += 1) {
            try stacks_part1.moveCrates(1, source, dest);
        }
        try stacks_part2.moveCrates(amount, source, dest);
    }
```

Ultimately, as you can see, I have just avoided making variable assignments in the function and this passes the test (and the puzzle).

I have checked for issues in the zig repo that might be related, and cannot find anything immediately obvious (search used is [this](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+assignment+loop)). I've looked on StackOverflow, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630797/how-to-create-2d-arrays-of-containers-in-zig), which does have some similarity to my issue (pointers seem a bit whack in while loops), but it's not the same.

I've scoured the zig documentation on loops and assignment, on the [site](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/), but don't see anything calling out this behaviour specifically.
I'm assuming I've either completely misunderstood something (or missed something that isn't well documented), or this is a bug — the language is under heavy active dev, after all.

I'm expecting that an assignment like I perform should work as expected — being a simple shorthand to avoid having to write out the repeated `self.stacks.items[source - 1]`, so I'm hopeful that this is something that I'm just doing wrong. Zig version is `v0.11.0-dev.537+36da3000c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array list stores `items` as a slice (a pointer to the first item plus length).
When you do

```
var source_list: ArrayList(u8) = self.stacks.items[source - 1];
```

you make a shallow copy of the array list. You might be confused by your knowledge of some higher-level languages where this would've copied a reference to an object of the array list, but in Zig this isn't the case. In Zig everything is a "value object".

When you call `shrinkRetainingCapacity` it changes the length property of the `items` slice, but the changes are done to the local copy of the array list. The "real" array list, that is stored in another array list, remain unaffected.

TL;DR You need to use a [pointer](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.0/#Pointers):

```
var source_list: *ArrayList(u8) = &self.stacks.items[source - 1];
```

This fixes the failing test.

Comment: That works brilliantly! Thank you so much. I still don't quite understand it fully, but I'll mull it over; this is very helpful.