# How can I create a HashMap on the heap in Zig?

Tags: zig

The conventional way to make an object on the heap is to make a create fn:

```
const Something = struct {
   a:Allocator,
   b:[1000]u8,
   pub fn create(a:Allocator) !*Something {
      var mem = try a.create(Something)
      mem.* = {
       .a =a,
       .b = undefined
      };
      return mem;
   }
}
```

But what about if I want to put a std lib ArrayHashMap on the heap? For example:

```
const StringStringArrayHashMap = std.StringArrayHashMap([]const u8);

fn makeMap(a:Allocator) StringStringArrayHashMap {
   return StringStringArrayHashMap.init(a);
}

const WithMap = struct {
   map:StringStringHashMap
};

fn fillMap(a:Allocator) !WithMap {
   var map = makeMap(a);
   try map.put("a", "hello");
   try map.put("b", "world");
   return WithMap { .map = map };
}
fn badMemory(a:Allocator) !void {
   const with_map = fillMap(a);
   _ = with_map;
}
```

`badMemory` will receive a `WithMap` but it's internal `map`, having been made on the stack in `fillMap` will be freed at the end of `fillMap` and consequently unsade in `badMemory`.

I can't see any way to make a valid HashMap without somehow hacking the internals of the zig stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the map on the heap the same way you did with `Something` type:

```
var map: *StringStringArrayHashMap = try allocator.create(StringStringArrayHashMap);
map.* = StringStringArrayHashMap.init(allocator);
```

> `badMemory` will receive a `WithMap` but it's internal `map`, having been made on the stack in `fillMap` will be freed at the end of `fillMap` and consequently unsafe in `badMemory`.

This is false. The map is safe to use in `badMemory` as it's copied to the stack in `badMemory`. (Or maybe the compiler could decide to pass it as a pointer, I'm not sure if [parameter's pass-by-value rule](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Pass-by-value-Parameters) applies to the return value. Doesn't matter here.) But you should probably be careful when copying the map or you might step into the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74709155/944911).

Comment: Thanks. I am not seeing the deep-copy of the stack that you're saying is happening... I don't seem x86 asm but I suppose the only way to understand is to go and look at it in godbolt.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "deep-copy of the stack".

The map is a `struct` that has pointers to the heap (memory provided by the allocator). In `badMemory` you have a copy of the `struct` that still retains valid pointers to the heap.